# When SendAsync is completed?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

Hi 
Is there a way to make sure all message bytes had sent with SendAsync, there is no information provided in the callback of this method so how can assume all the message had sent ?? And whats the maximum size of message we can send using socket in on Send operation ? is there any limitation exists or we can send data as large as we need ??

Thanks for clear responses ;)

Comment: Obviously it wont just stop sending bytes unless there was an exception. Maybe trust the type to do what it was designed for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the callback is called without an error indication then the message has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the information you need is in the callback:

```
    private void SendSAEA_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs sendSAEA)
    {        
            if (sendSAEA.BytesTransferred == 0 || sendSAEA.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                Close();
            }
            else
            {
                 // Process sendSAEA.BytesTransferred
            }
     }
```

Also, the buffer we can send in one Send operation, according to MSDN:

- You can control the buffer size with: Socket.SendBufferSize.
- The default is 8192.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendbuffersize.aspx)

And, for SendAsync:

> For message-oriented sockets, do not
>   exceed the maximum message size of the
>   underlying Windows sockets service
>   provider. If the data is too long to
>   pass atomically through the underlying
>   service provider, no data is
>   transmitted and the SendAsync method
>   throws a SocketException with the
>   SocketAsyncEventArgs.SocketError set
>   to the native Winsock WSAEMSGSIZE
>   error code (10040).

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync.aspx)